# Regex para obtener un número sólo si no hay un string antes

Tags: java, regex

Tengo líneas del siguiente estilo:

```
fecha vencimiento 20-12-2017
fecha 20-12-2017
```

Y lo que ando buscando es la forma de hacer una expresión regular que en caso de que antes o después de la fecha aparezca la palabra `vencimiento` no matchee.

Hasta ahora tengo la siguiente regex para reconocer las fechas:

```
(\b[0-9]{1,2}(/|-)[0-1]([0-2]*)(/|-)[0-9]{4}\b)
```

Pero no encuentro manera de validar lo de la palabra "vencimiento".

Comment: Siempre habría **exactamente** 1 espacio entre "vencimiento" y el número?

Comment: Nono, podrían aparecer varios

Comment: Y recién comentaste que podría aparecer atrás o adelante... Entonces, "obtener una fecha, siempre y cuando la palabra `vencimiento` no esté en *todo* el texto"?

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizar las **funciones** ya definidas de la clase **String** *(contains , replaceall, substring)*?

Comment: Perdón @Dev.Joel, vi tu comentario después de publicar (sino hubiese esperado a que te conteste).

Comment: Hola, disculpen la tardanza de la respuesta. La palabra vencimiento siempre va **antes** de la fecha, en el comentario que mencionas me confundí. Gracias por tomarse la molestia. No uso la función es que si o si necesito una regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**¿Cómo encontrar una fecha, siempre y cuando no se encuentre `vencimiento` dentro del texto?**

La forma que recomendaría es utilizar 2 expresiones:

1. Buscar que `vencimiento` no esté en el texto (preferiblemente **[sin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))** una expresión regular)
2. Capturar la fecha.

Esto puede ser muchísimo más efectivo que validar todo dentro del mismo regex.

---

Si aún así se busca realizar todo dentro de una misma expresión:

**¿Cómo encontrar una fecha, siempre y cuando no se encuentre `vencimiento` dentro de la misma línea?**

```
^(?!.*\bvencimiento\b).*\b([0-3]?\d[-/][01]?\d[-/]\d{4})\b
```

Como se ve, con `^` estamos anclando la expresión al comienzo de la línea, utilizando el flag [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE).

La estructura más importante en esta expresión es el inspección negativa (*[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*), de la forma `(?!expr)` y que básicamente significa "no está seguido por `expr`. En caso de que `expr` coincida con el texto, el intento actual falla.
De esta forma, al utilizar `^(?!.*\bvencimiento\b)` nos garantizamos que la palabra `vencimiento` no esté en toda la línea.

Por último, cabe mencionar que modifiqué la parte de la fecha en tu expresión, ya que `[0-1]([0-2]*)` sólo coincide con números como `00`, `11`, `112112`, etc; pero no coincide con `05`.

La parte de la fecha la estamos encerrando en paréntesis, de modo de generar un [grupo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), y poder obtener sólo esa parte específica con [`Matcher#group(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-).

Es decir, capturamos una fecha por línea (sólo una), siempre que `vencimiento` no esté en la misma línea.

**Código:**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "^(?!.*\\bvencimiento\\b).*\\b([0-3]?\\d[-/][01]?\\d[-/]\\d{4})\\b";
final String texto = "fecha vencimiento 20-12-2017\nfecha 20-12-2017\notra: 12/05/2016";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

if (matcher.find()) {
    do {
        System.out.println("Fecha: " + matcher.group(1));
    } while (matcher.find());
} else {
    System.out.println("No se encontró ninguna fecha");
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Fecha: 20-12-2017
Fecha: 12/05/2016
```

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/zZxYO3

---

**¿Y cómo encontrar una fecha, siempre y cuando `vencimiento` no sea la palabra que la precede (con cualquier cantidad de `\W` en el medio)?**

En ese caso, utilizaríamos una inspección hacia atrás negativa (*[negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*). La construcción `(?<!expr)` Se podría traducir como "*la posición actual no está precedida por `expr`*".

En resumen, sería:

```
(?:^\W*|\b(?<!vencimiento)\W+)([0-3]?\d[-/][01]?\d[-/]\d{4}\b)
```

que, en cada límite de palabra, verifica que no esté precedido por `vencimiento`.

**Código:**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "(?:^\\W*|\\b(?<!vencimiento)\\W+)([0-3]?\\d[-/][01]?\\d[-/]\\d{4}\\b)";
final String texto = "fecha vencimiento 20-12-2017\nfecha 20-12-2017\notra: 12/05/2016";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

if (matcher.find()) {
    do {
        System.out.println("Fecha: " + matcher.group(1));
    } while (matcher.find());
} else {
    System.out.println("No se encontró ninguna fecha");
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Fecha: 20-12-2017
Fecha: 12/05/2016
```

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/ccrt55

---

Alternativamente, para no estar revisando hacia atrás en cada límite de palabra, podríamos verificar hacia adelante, algo que podría ser un poco más eficiente en textos largos. La estrategia sería: ir consumiendo posición por posición, viendo si la siguiente palabra es `vencimiento` y, si es, consumir la siguiente palabra de forma [posesiva](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), de modo que no pueda volver hacia atrás.

```
\G\W*+(?:(?:vencimiento\W+)?+\w+\W+)*?([0-3]?\d[-/][01]?\d[-/]\d{4}\b)
```

Al usar [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html), estamos anclando el inicio de cada intento al comienzo del texto o al fin de la coincidencia anterior (si hay más de una fecha en el texto).

**Código:**

```
final String regex = "\\G\\W*+(?:(?:vencimiento\\W+)?+\\w+\\W+)*?([0-3]?\\d[-/][01]?\\d[-/]\\d{4}\\b)";
final String texto = "fecha vencimiento 20-12-2017\nfecha 20-12-2017\notra: 12/05/2016";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

if (matcher.find()) {
    do {
        System.out.println("Fecha: " + matcher.group(1));
    } while (matcher.find());
} else {
    System.out.println("No se encontró ninguna fecha");
}
```

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/Gahqjl

Comment: Simplemente perfecto! Mil gracias!

Comment: Lo acabo de notar, me va a traer complicaciones. Es mucho drama la validación de que esté solo **antes** de la fecha? Disculpame las molestias

Comment: @Genarito - Agregué las 2 alternativas en la respuesta. Estaba evitando este tipo de solución ya que es menos clara y un poco menos eficiente (nada para preocuparse).

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba! Te agradezco por haberte tomado la molestia de extender la respuesta. Saludos!